# how does the softlink vimdiff be implemented

Tags: linux, vim

I found that the `vimdiff` utility is just a soft link to vim. both of the two are located under `/usr/bin/` in my Suse11 box. and `vimdfiff` is a soft link to vim. the interesting thing is that, `vimdiff file1 file2` is actually the equivalent of `vim -d file1 file2`, so in that
sense, the `-d` option is automatically embedded in the soft link, so my question is as simple as
How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vim in its `main()` function uses `argv[0]` to differentiate its executable name `vim` or `vimdiff`, or etc.

[Link to vim main.c](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/main.c#1507)  that performs this check to differentiate `rvim`, `rview`, `gvim`, `gview`, `vimdiff`, `gvimdiff`, `ex`, `exim`.

```
/*
 * Check for: [r][e][g][vi|vim|view][diff][ex[im]]
 * If the next character is "e" we run in Easy mode.
 * If the next character is "g" we run the GUI version.
 * If the next characters are "view" we start in readonly mode.
 * If the next characters are "diff" or "vimdiff" we start in diff mode.
 * If the next characters are "ex" we start in Ex mode.  If it's followed
 * by "im" use improved Ex mode.
 */
```

Comment: and `ex`, and `gvim`, and `view`, and others

Comment: Thx Benoit. included your findings too.